# Tool for creating a WAV given a function of time/sample

Tags: software, synthesis, wav

What software could I use to create a WAV file from a function of sample number?

I am building an implementation of Group Additive Synthesis in a modular softsynth and I just need a simple way of creating the wavetables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is a tool like Matlab (from the Matthworks).  You can download a free trial, but you would have to learn some prograsmming (or Matlabs language).  But I believe it can create a .wav or .aiff file from a function that synthesizes a waveform or a complex signal.

Comment: There's also Scilab which is a free alternative to Matlab. The function to save to a wave file is savewave - https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/savewave.html

Answer (score 1):

If simple waveforms are enough, [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) is a (free and) convenient tool to go for. In the version I use (2.1.2), the following are creatable per default (please see below for plugin add-on):

- Simple waveforms (you can specify frequency, amplitude and duration):

  - sinus wave
  - square wave
  - saw wave
  - square without aliasing
- Chirps (amplitude and frequency changes over time (additionally, interpolation curve is selectable here ("linear" vs. "logarithmic"))

  - Same waveforms as for "simple waveforms".
- DTMF tones
- Noise (you can specify amplitude and duration):

  - white
  - pink
  - brown
- Simple risset drums (editable frequency, decay, center frequency of noise, width of noise band, amount of moise in mix, amplitude).
- Simple pluck strings (editable duration, fade out type and midi note height).

**Furthermore, there are plugins** that might be of interest in your case. See [this one](https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?p=109386&sid=a98efe3b10941d1e9115b4a5a1bf0b72#p109386) for example.

You can export your generated waveform in many audio formats, including several `.wav` formats with different bit depth.

Comment: It's sine wave, not sinus. That was too small an edit for me to make, so i'll make it a comment